# How should I set up my application structure to deploy on multiple domains (like Amazon)?

Tags: database-design, web, architecture

I'm working on an ecommerce site, and there's going to be multiple domains -- one for each region. It's pretty similar to Amazon where amazon.com has different products/currencies from amazon.br, amazon.co.uk, etc. One of the requirements is that there should be a master admin to manage all the regional sites, generate reports about all orders and such.

I have thought of two ways to structure my website

## Scenario 1

In the first scenario we have only one database which is aware of the regional domains. Basically there's a column called 'region' in some of the tables and we can use to filter our requests depending on the domain. This is captured in the picture bellow

[image: Architecture 1]

## Scenario 2

In the second scenario we have a database for each regional domain. This makes things simpler in terms of queries and setting it up, but I'm not sure how we could do things like generating reports about the orders of all sites.

[image: Architecture 2]

So my question is -- which scenario should I go for, or is there a third scenario? how should I structure things and what factors should I keep in mind?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that theres few other structure but the two you've mentioned is the most commonly way, from an E-commerce expert I would go with the second structure, and the reason is to know the weaknesses and strengths of each regions I mean for example if you are selling boats in the states and you divided each state as a region, people in Texas won't buy a boat as much as people in California for example, so you won't spend effort and money on marketing for boat in Texas. I hope you got the point.